# Solving $\int\left(\sqrt\frac{gx}{a\ln(x)+d+cx}\right)dx$ using Risch algorithm

Tags: integration

I was solving some problems in particle physics, and i got stuck with such an equation,

$$\int\left(\sqrt\frac{gx}{a\ln(x)+b+cx}\right)dx$$

The problem was to formulate a function of time and displacement of a particle colliding with it's antiparticle with considering the Uehling correction of the Coulomb potential. After many steps i got stuck with the equation above. I've no idea how to solve this equation, i tried many times and i always failed. $a,b,c$ and $g$ are constants that i substituted with other complicated formulas in my equation so that the equation don't look huge.

I've heard of a method called the Risch algorithm, but i don't understand it really much, maybe this will be the key somehow.

Can some one please help me out with this equation. Thank you all guys.

Comment: Integrals which are asked in books or in exams are do-able others may or not be so;  clarify this point in the question. Also you could have written it as $\int \sqrt{\frac{x}{p \ln x +qx+r}} dx$ to receive more attention

Comment: no it's not in books or exams, i was thinking of a problem in physics and this equation suddenly came up, and i don't know what to do. Whatever, thank you for you suggestion @DrZafarAhmedDSc, i will edit the equation

Comment: Better, mention the whole context here itself. People will appreciate it more.

Comment: ok@DrZafarAhmedDSc

Comment: I think this is the work for the most general applications of the Risch algorithm, and as such, integrability may depend on the values of the parameters $a,b,c,g$.

Comment: Are there any other ways?@orion

Comment: If, as suggested, you consider $\int \sqrt{\frac{x}{p \ln x +qx+r}} dx$, I doubt about closed form solution if $q\ne 0$